# Cpanel email disk usage, how to clear properly?

Tags: cpanel, whm

i recently inherited the job of looking after all the servers at work, nothing too complicated but beginning to notice a trend of disk space running out.

One of the main mail servers/old recycled servers has Cpanel installed and when querying its large disk usage on WHM i noticed mail folder was sat at 88GB taking up a huge amount.

Investigating the email account a few people have 6gb-9gb worth of email space being used however accessing the webmail it only shows their inbox with 30 messages or so on.

How do you go about clearing an email accounts usage properly without deleting the entire account?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the old mails, you can set a cron for the same. Please refer the [post](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/having-issues-getting-cron-job-to-work.389492/page-2#post1570381)